# Maximun value for |V| given |E| and grade

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $G = (V, E)$ is a connected graph with $| E | = 17$ and $δ (v) ≥ 3$ for all $v ∈ V$. What is the maximum value for $| V |$?

Comment: First of all, I have no idea what $\delta(v)$ means. But where are you stuck? Have you tried to compute the answer for $|E|=3$? $|E|=4$ or $5$? Do these examples suggest an approach?

Comment: It is number of verteces connected with v I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think 11 is the answer. For 12 verteces we have $12  \cdot 3 / 2 = 18$ minimum edges. End for 11 we will have 1 vertex degree 4 and 10 of degree 3.